# ::selection working only after forced re-render in inpector using - Chrome + ReactJs

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, reactjs

I have a div with the following css:

```
.someTopParentClass .someParentClass .someClass::selection {
    background: #ffcc00;
}
```

This is working without reactjs.

The class does show in the inspector with the correct color, but the color is not really applied.

When using reactjs, the background on selection stays blue until I go into Chrome's inspector and only after I change *any* css property of *any* class - the selection becomes the correct color :/

The .someTopParentClass class is renders dynamically on button click.
My guess is that Chrome doesn't realize correctly for some reason that the parent class was added - although in the inspector it shows the correct .someClass and the correct color.

This issue seems to happen only in Chrome (Works in Edge,Firefox)

**Update**

I reproduced the issue in JSFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/rmindel/r3581ewt/

Where do I open a bug for Chrome :/ ?

For now my solution was to change the color of the text from black to #000001 so Chrome will know it needs to re-paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened a bug for Chrome:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685174#c6

The workaround for me is as stated - 
"For now my solution was to change the color of the text from black to #000001 so Chrome will know it needs to re-paint."